# Can I call a predefined function inside jQuery scroll()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

So I have a function with an argument and I want to call it inside a scroll function. I want to do this so that I can call the function without needing to wait for a scroll, and so that I can reuse the function with different arguments.

```
function myFunction(arg) {
    // do something
};
```

I want to call this with:

```
$(window).scroll(myFunction(arg));
```

But it doesn't work.

So far everything I have seen includes an anonymous function call inside the `scroll()` like:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // do something
});
```

However, like I said earlier doesn't allow me to reuse my function with different arguments, or to call my function in a different way.

Is it possible to call a predefined function from inside `scroll()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes if you have arguments then call an anonymous function and call your function from within that. As such:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
   myFunction(myArguments);
});
```

Comment: Perfect! You know, I thought I tired that, but sometimes it just takes someone else to say try it again.

Comment: Yeah for some odd reason javascript won't allow arguments to be passed by event handlers. This is the same when calling from setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: @BrettEast don't forget to select this as the correct answer. Thanks